# DataColumnCollection is not working as expected, seems like a culture issue?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have this snippet of code:

```
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("artikalartikaltip");
            table.Columns.Add("artikaljedinicamjere");

            DataColumn col1 = table.Columns["ArtikalArtikalTip"];
            DataColumn col2 = table.Columns["ArtikalJedinicaMjere"];
```

If I run this code then col1 gets asked DataColumn object but col2 is null.

If I change the string to ArtikaljedinicaMjere (note the lowercase J) than col2 gets it's columns.

I'm suspecting that the culprit is current culture which is set to hr-HR (Croatian). In Croatian language there is a single letter Lj. But, if I call ToCharArray() method I get the same number of chars in lowercase and camelcase variants.

Can someone explain what is happening and how indexer works in this collection?